# Flutter accessibility tooltip for buttons

Tags: android, flutter, button, tooltip, accessibility

Good day.  I am developing a app for blind users like me.  I want to use tooltip to describe button use.  But with my searches I only get to long press to get the message.  I did set the wait property of tooltip to 0 but that do not work also.  I need to be able to use tooltip as in the case of floating action button or icon button that give me immediate response.  Do anyone know how to get that to happen or am I stuck with only using floating action button or icon button with buildin tooltip.  For long pressing everytime on buttons is not really helpfull in a accessibility app.  I am developing for a android app.  Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Woah. Nice! Can ya tell me how exactly u want the tooltip to trigger? And how you want the button to trigger? I think I might be able to help.

Comment: Hi. When using talkback you hve to click twice to activate a button.  So when the user touch the button the tooltip must be triggered and explain the use of the button. Thanks

Comment: For example I do not want the user to click the button but just on touch.  So if home screen say have 2 flat buttons 'scan' and 'generate'.  When user move over screen and talkback give feedback that the user has touched the scan or generate button a message must be triggered saying 'scan for nbarcodes' or 'generate new barcode for own use'

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Ok. I think I get the idea. Instead of using a button, try using `GestureDetector` with its child as a `Container` or `Card` (aka creating your own button). In `GestureDetector`, you can then configure `onTap` function to trigger the tooltip and `onDoubleTap` to trigger the stated function. Like so:

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    // Trigger the tooltip here.
  },
  onDoubleTap: () {
    // Execute the function stated in the tooltip here.
  },
  child: const Card(child: Text('Some Button Name')),
),
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Thanks will look if that works.  But how to     // Trigger the tooltip here. Must I call the tooltip function there?  Tooltip( message: 'Scann barcodes', );

Comment: Ok, nevermind. I thought you were invoking a function to read the message, not using a widget. Wait, let me think of something else.

Comment: Will `SnackBar` work for screen readers? Something like this:
`final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Yay! A SnackBar!'));
Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);`

Comment: Not sure, never used one.  But will give it a try.  It is a pitty that all buttons do not have the tooltip: '', property like the floating action button.  So first have to read up on SnackBar!')); .  Thank you very much for your reply

Comment: Of course! If ya have any queries, do ask. I've no idea how the screen reader works and all, but I'll try to see on it

Comment: Thanks alot, you gave me some ideas to work on.